# Prevent scrolling to top when click tab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scroll, pg-search

A user can click tabs, filtering the jobs on my page by category.
When a user clicks the tab, the page hits a search (I use the pg_search gem).

Problem: when clicking the tab, the page reloads and scrolls to the top. This is very bad for my UX. How do I prevent scrolling to top and keep on the height of the tabs-banner instead?

Here is my html.erb file:

```
<div class="tabs-banner">
  <div class="tabs">
    <a class="tab active" href="/vacancies?utf8=✓&query=">
      <h2 style="color:white;"><br>All Jobs</h2>
    </a>
    <a class="tab" href="/vacancies?utf8=✓&query=developer">
      <h2><br>Developer</h2>
    </a>
    <a class="tab" href="/vacancies?utf8=✓&query=marketing">
      <h2><br>Marketing</h2>
    </a>
    <a class="tab hidden-xs" href="/vacancies?utf8=✓&query=design">
      <h2><br>Design</h2>
    </a>
    <a class="tab hidden-xs" href="/vacancies?utf8=✓&query=finance">
      <h2><br>Finance</h2>
    </a>
    <a class="tab hidden-xs" href="/vacancies?utf8=✓&query=internships">
      <h2><br>Internships</h2>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add a javascript handler which prevents the default event.

Comment: could you give an example here? my javascript skills still suck...

Comment: In jQuery you can just write `$('.someSelector').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault()})`.

Comment: total noob question: do i put that in my html with <script></script> tags just like that?

Comment: No not really. What you are asking is actually a pretty broad question that requires familiarity with javascript to solve. You not only have to prevent the default event but also have to use ajax to fetch the new content. I would recommend you start with some basic javascript tutorials.

Comment: okay thanks. thought there would be a quick-fix for that issue maybe...

Comment: Not really. You can use anchors (also known as a hash) in the url to link to an element with a specific id on the page (for example /vacancies?utf8=✓&query=marketing#foo) which the browser will automatically scroll to when it refreshes the page. But avoiding a reload entails the use of ajax.

Comment: @Sabrina, is it your html.erb file or generated html from the page? If it is first - why you don't use an iterator for links?

Comment: @vasilia, that works, thanks a lot.@max thanks for your solution - i might get back to this when i am a bit more comfortable with jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As max said, you can use anchors as a quick fix. Add id to `tabs-banner` div and use it in the links

```
<div class="tabs-banner" id="category-tabs">
  <div class="tabs">
    <a class="tab active" href="/vacancies?utf8=✓&query=#category-tabs"">
      <h2 style="color:white;"><br>All Jobs</h2>
    </a>
    # all other tabs
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Sabrina, happy to help! Please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer if it helped